# Unable to rename and remove pandas Index - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is like as shown below

[image]

Though I know the column names are 'FR', 'ig' and 'te' with the help of below command.

```
dataFramesDict['Tri'].columns
```

[image]

What does name = 'level_1' mean here? Moreover, I also don't see `subject_ID` in the columns or index list. What is `subject_ID` here?

How do I get the output to be like as shown below

[image]

I tried the below code to rename 'level_1' to 'subject_ID' but it doesn't work

```
dataFramesDict['Tri'].index = dataFramesDict['Tri'].index.rename('subject_ID')
```

Please note that the data is just a sample data. I am only interested in changing the first column name and dropping that 'level_1'. Nothing to do with data

I am unable to create dataframe of this type through sample code. The above shown dataframe is a result of another complex code. So, I have provided a screenshot of dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
df.columns.name= ''
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Instead of `title`, it is `df.columns.name = ' '`

Comment: Will update the answer soon. Currently it doesn't allow me to update

Comment: approve the answer if you found it helpful

Comment: I meant marking your answer as solution. It didn't allow me to update earlier due to time limit. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Can you help me with this post? Can you help me with this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285680/dont-drop-all-nas-during-stack-operation-in-python